# How to replicate android:editable="false" in code?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In the layout you can set the `EditText` widget to be non-editable via the `android:editable attribute`.

How can I do this in code?  I need to make the `EditText` widget to be editable depending on conditions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think an [`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) that rejects all changes is a good solution:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            return src.length() < 1 ? dst.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:** dlazar suggested (below) to change the `return` to `dst.subSequence(dstart, dend)` to overcome behavior that removes words.

Comment: This does not work as expected. In this solution, when you click on an auto-correct word suggestion, the selected word is removed.

Comment: unable to verify it atm but it sounds like @dlazar already recognized this problem and suggested a solution - added it to the answer

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite? (Make the editText EDITABLE)

Comment: If you select a part of text, can clear it with typing any character.

Answer (score 45):

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setClickable(false);
```

this ensure the `EditText` control can't be selected and focused, so it can't be edited.

Comment: But it also can't be selected and copied.

Answer (score 32):

I just tried this myself,

To disable editing text:

```
.setFocusable(false);
```

this also sets setFocusableInTouchMode to false!

To enable editing text:

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

this also sets setFocusable to true;

Answer (score 16):

The best way to do this is with this single line of code:

```
textView.setKeyListener(null);
```

The docs say for this method:

> Sets the key listener to be used with
>   this TextView. This can be null to
>   disallow user input.

Comment: This may work, but what if you need to switch between editable and non-editable due to some criteria? You'd have to create your own KeyListener in order to set it back to editable, which feels wrong.

Comment: Has other side effects, like killing selection for copy, too.

Comment: What Christopher suggested should work. It allows you to select and copy text from the field just the same as if you had defined the field not editable from the xml (I don't know what James is talking about, but it works fine at least on Android 2.2.). Looking at the source code that's pretty much what is done when the xml attribute enabled is set to false for any TextView. As per the documentation you may need to call setFocusable(true) after calling setKeyListener(null).

Comment: @John
You can call `getKeyListener()` first and stash it for later use can't you (if it was previously set)? Or perhaps map the getInputType to some key listener manually. Or just force some known good key listener. E.g. you should be able to set (didn't test it) the default TextKeyListener with this: `textView.setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance());`

Comment: KeyListener docs: "Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so. The default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it for some key presses to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier."

Answer (score 6):

```
android:editable="false" 
android:inputType="none"
```

in your xml
 or

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mEdit.setEnabled(false);
```

or

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mEdit.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
        mEditText.setFocusable(false);
        mEditText.setClickable(false);
        mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        mEditText.setLongClickable(false);
        mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

This will completely disable EditText, disable long press if you don't want user to open edit text options.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see a related method for that attribute in the EditText
class.  However, there are other similar things you could use such as
`android:focus/setFocusable(boolean)` or create another TextView whose
`android:editable="false"` and use `setVisiblilty()` to switch between the
editable and not editable views.  If you use `View.GONE` the user will
never know there are two EditTexts.

If your feeling ambitious you could probably do something with the EditText's `onTextChanged` listener like having it react with a `setText`.

Comment: Considering the flaky nature of the KeyListeners (relative to soft keyboard), I was discouraged from messing with those or the edit text properties.  I consider this the most robust answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType)) ?
It's described as:

> Sets the text that this TextView is to display (see setText(CharSequence)) and also sets whether it is stored in a styleable/spannable buffer **and whether it is editable**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I just tried and it makes no difference whatsoever.  Furthermore, there isn't any documentation on what the enum values even mean.

Answer (score 3):

[Posting a new answer, since I can't comment on Josef's answer.]

The input filter works fine, but it has a subtle bug in it: typing over a selection will delete all the text.

For example, say you have the text `"foo"` in the `EditText`.  If you select it all (e.g., by double-clicking on it) and type `'a'`, the text will disappear.  This is because the `InputFilter` will be called as:

```
filter("a", 0, 1, "foo", 0, 3);
```

The proposed input filter will return the empty string in this case (because `src.length() < 1` is `false`), which explains the missing text.

The solution is to simply return `dst.subSequence(dstart, dend)` in the filter function.  This will work fine even for deletions.

Answer (score 3):

I guess

```
Edittext.setEnabled(false);
```

through code

and

```
android:enabled="false"
```

through xml.Also check this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384004/make-edittext-readonly).

They should work and you can enable again programatically     `Edittext.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: I dont want to take the ownership of that answer, I just made the correction which was necessary to make it work, ok. In rails in my code the ID of both text and drop down generates automatically and they are same, so I need to add classes and compare using class, mind, it...even if I am a beginner, I dont need any credits of others....I am commenting here as I dont have any other way to contact you, thank you bye.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34760933/5239247

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to also point out an alternative solution that works nicely if you are creating new instances of an EditView. You can override the method getDefaultEditable() as suggested by the docs to return false. E.g.

```
EditText view = new EditText(DiscountCalculator.this) {
    public boolean getDefaultEditable() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found for this scenario is to create 2 layouts.  One is editable and one is not.  You may have to create more than 2 layouts based on various conditions.  Store the conditions in SharedPreferences or other means and load the relevant layout based on conditions after restarting the Activity.  Here's an example:

in onCreate() of the activity:

```
    configuration = new Configuration(this.getSharedPreferences(Configuration.SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    manualSettingsMode = configuration.isManualSettingsMode();
    if(manualSettingsMode){
        setContentView(R.layout.editableconfigurationsettings);
    }else {
        setContentView(R.layout.configurationsettings);
    }
```

The activity can be restarted based on testing for condition and calling functions as:

```
private void setManualEditing(){
    configuration.set_isManualSettingsMode(true);
    this.recreate();
}

private void setAutoEditing(){
    configuration.set_isManualSettingsMode(false);
    this.recreate();
}
```

Hope this helps.  There really has to be a better solution, but this is what I've been doing.  Ideally, one would be able to do this on individual fields and not have to reload the activity / layouts. -bobby

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct way to achieve the desired effect is:

```
mEditView.setText("my text", BufferType.NORMAL);
```

If you want to switch between editable and non-editable you can do the following:

```
// Switch to non-editable
mEditView.setText(mEditView.getText(), BufferType.NORMAL);

// Switch back to editable
mEditView.setText(mEditView.getText(), BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: Try substituting mEditView.getText().toString() instead, and see if that works. I think this might actually work for you.

Comment: I think this only effects on the buffer and that doesn't make the field in the ui uneditable as then I suppose it will just contain immutable buffer that it gets discarded if there are any changes.

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't help much, prevents user from modifying input contents but in a really silly way.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (XXX) {
                return "";
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }});
```

Comment: Will you please add some details?