# Can we have uneditable text in edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am using an `EditText`. Is it possible to have a part of text uneditable and the rest editable in the same `EditText`?

Answer (score 16):

You could use

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

or

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

although disabling the `EditText` does currently not ignore input from the on-screen keyboard (I think that's a bug).

Depending on the application it might be better to use an [`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) that rejects all changes:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            return src.length() < 1 ? dst.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";
        }
    }
});
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditablefalse-in-code) question.

Comment: For show/hide password fields, the text content is cleared if you use this trick and then change the input type (`editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD)`). The workaround is to temporarily set the filters to the empty array while you change the input type.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a TextChangedListener where you make sure those parts of your text wont get `deleted/overwritten`.

```
class TextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                makeSureNothingIsDeleted();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
}
```

---

```
    TextChangedListener tcl = new TextChangedListener();
    my_editable.addTextChangedListener(tcl);
```