# How to make an EditText uneditable/disabled

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText in which the user should not be able to provide input. So I tried disabling it,by

```
edittext.setEnabled(false);
edittext.setClickable(false);
```

But still when I press the "next" button in the softKeyboard from some other EditText it directs me to the one which should not be editable and I am able to insert values into it. How to avoid this?

Comment: where do you use these commands? in which event?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910973/why-can-i-type-into-a-disabled-edittext

Comment: your que is similar to this que 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code

Comment: The whole point of the **EditText** is to allow the user to **edit** its contents. Is there any reason you're not using TextView?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This works fine; just set focusable property of your edittext to "false" and you are done.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:cursorVisible="true">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: it is not an acceptable answer why because if we long click on EditText we are able to paste new data using this solution. and the correct solution is EditTextInput.setKeyListener(null);

Comment: @Venkat I agree that the answer shouldn't have been accepted. We just experienced a problem where `isFocusable = false` still allowed to long-tap and copy-paste anything in the input that was supposed to be disabled. Your answer actually does what was expected.

Answer (score 36):

don't messed up with your self. just simple to work use below one

First, save the EditText's key listener:

```
KeyListener mKeyListener = yourTextView.getKeyListener();
yourTextView.setKeyListener(null);
```

Then if you want to enable editing again, assign the saved listener back:

```
yourTextView.setKeyListener(mKeyListener);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933056/edit-text-key-listener)

Comment: This is the best soultion if you want to do this from code.

Comment: What to do if I want to enable it after disabling it?

Comment: @kirtan403 set your textview.setKeyListener(your listener);

Comment: If you guys wanted to enable editing afterwards, you need to first store/save the KeyListener via edittext.getKeyListener() and then assigning it back later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933056/edit-text-key-listener

Comment: Note that using `setInputType` afterwards resets the key listener.

Comment: this is wrong. you can still long press and cut/copy/paste etc.

Comment: This is better than setEnable which causes keyboard collapse.

Answer (score 18):

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(null);
```

No need to remove focus and setting clickable false.

Just remove key listener and you are done.

**Also tested with Android 6.0**

Comment: This is great because it won't make the EditText text color change.

Answer (score 7):

Ok. I did something like this and got the result.

```
    edittext.setEnabled(false);
    edittext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    edittext.setClickable(false);
    edittext.setFocusable(false);
    edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new textChange() });
    edittext.setInputType(0);

       class textChange implements InputFilter {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
android:focusable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

Adding these two fields to your EditText will disables the focus and also disables the copy pasting data into your EditText field.

Comment: Was looking for an XML-only solution and this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding

`edittext.setFocusable(false);
 edittest.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`

Comment: `setFocusable(false)` will automatically disable `setFocusableInTouchMode`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2771)

`editText.setEnabled(false);` and `editText.setFocusable(false);` will achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In your EditText Xml Code . Paste below line.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="false"
```

worked for me.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use imeOptions attribute to change that button in softKeyboard to done

android:imeOptions="actionDone"

add it to EditText just previous to the one you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be somebody helpful.
I've found one implementation:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //for edit text
        return locked;
    }
```

where `locked` is locked state.

of course, i have to use `editText.setOnTouchListener(<listener>);`