# Edit Text key listener

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

I have an `edittext` and a button in my layout and in my code I'm setting `keyListener` of the `edittext` as null

```
    editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

so that I cannot type into my `edittext`. Now on my button click I should be able to type into my `ediitext`. How can I do that. It's a simple problem, but I'm not able to find any solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm probably late now but, this is the way I do it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private KeyListener listener;
    private EditText editText;

    public void onCreate(...)
    {
        editText = ... // Get EditText from somewhere
        listener = editText.getKeyListener(); // Save the default KeyListener!!!
        editText.setKeyListener(null); // Disable input
    }

    // When you click your button, restore the default KeyListener
    public void buttonClickHandler(...)
    {
        editText.setKeyListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Basically, you first save the **EditText**'s default **KeyListener** before you call `setKeyListener(null)`.  Then, when you click your button, you call `setKeyListener` again, passing the default listener you previously saved.

Comment: Just what I wanted... Haven't tried it, but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this :

```
// When you click your button, restore the default KeyListener
public void buttonClickHandler(...)
{
    editText.setKeyListener(new EditText(getApplicationContext()).getKeyListener());
}
```

Comment: I think rainai 's answer is more correct. That will keep the original keylistener of the edittext

Comment: i tray rainai's method, but it doesn't work for me, So i but this method , because it is worked. :)

Comment: rainai's method didn't work for me either. This one worked though.

Comment: i tried this method, but the keyboard not appear when I click the input. Anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 2):

its bug in android See here [Bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2771).

But in xml file you can do it.Using `android:editable="false"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:editable="false" <<<<<<<
</EditText>
```

Comment: Sorry if we do like that we will still be able to type into the edittext in disabled mode also. I cannot accept that as an answer though it may give user a feeling that he may not be able to type into edittext

Comment: What I want to do is through code only. Because when I tap that button again. I want to make the property of the edittext as it was before(Could not type into it) So I cannot go for xml... But I will check if there is any property like editable in java code... Mean while if you find an answer please help me by posting it...Thankyou