# How to enable or disable an editText by selecting a spinner

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spinner

The problem is that it disables text editing but in case 1 of the Switch when you have to activate it again it does not

This is the code I am using.

```
public class ejemolo extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] Items = {
            "Dc amps a Kw",
            "Ac una fase amp a kw ",
            "Ac trifasicaamps a kw (linia a linea de voltaje)",
                "Ac trifasica amps a kw (linia a voltaje neutral)",

        };

        Spinner s1;

        private String[] listOfObjects;

        EditText ampEditText , voltageEditText , powerfactorEditText  ;

        TextView text1 , text2 , text3, text4 ;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ejemolo);

            FloatingActionButton buttonback = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonback);
            buttonback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(v.getContext() , Weight.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent ,0);
                }
            });

            FloatingActionButton buttonhome = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonhome);
            buttonhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(v.getContext() , MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent ,0);
                }
            });

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAmp);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Items);

            s1.setAdapter(adapter);

            ampEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampEditText);
            voltageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.voltageEditText);

            powerfactorEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.powerfactorEditText);

            //text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tonsTextResult1);
            //text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tonsTextResult2);

            listOfObjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.object_array4);

    //        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAmp);

            final android.icu.text.DecimalFormat decimals = new android.icu.text.DecimalFormat("0.00"); /** la cantidad de digitos decimales que se muestra */

           // ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfObjects);

            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    switch (position) {

                        case 0 :

                            int indzex = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            powerfactorEditText.setFocusable(false);
                            powerfactorEditText.setEnabled(false);
                            powerfactorEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
                            powerfactorEditText.setKeyListener(null);
                            powerfactorEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                            break;

                        case 1:

                            int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                            powerfactorEditText.setEnabled(true);
                            powerfactorEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                            powerfactorEditText.setFocusable(true);
                            powerfactorEditText.setCursorVisible(true);

                            break;

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> f
        }

    }
```

I want to enable the issue in spinner case 2..

Comment: at first glance, the `backgroundcolor` will kill the `EditText` background. remove the` backgroundcolor` line and retry

Comment: @rupps I want in the first case the editTex is deleted and is shown in the second case

Comment: then just `powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE)` would be enough to hide it

Comment: @rupps It works, to show it use ,                         powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: yeah :) you guessed it right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to enable EditText because of this line in Case 0:
powerfactorEditText.setKeyListener(null);

Please remove this line and test otherwise set proper Keylistener.

Refer Link below:
[Edit Text key listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933056/edit-text-key-listener)

Answer (score 0):

I use this method :

```
switch (position) {
    case 0 :
        int indzex = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        //powerfactorEditText.setFocusable(false);
        powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    break;

    case 1:
        int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        //powerfactorEditText.setFocusable(true);
        powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
}
```