# Cannot change EditText back to being editable

Tags: android

I want to make my `EditText` not `Editable` through java code, and then get it back to being editable, but it seems that it cannot be changed back.

```
 noteDetailsview.setClickable(false);
 noteDetailsview.setFocusable(false);
 noteDetailsview.setClickable(true);
 noteDetailsview.setFocusable(true);
```

Now it is still not editable. How can I make it editable again.

Comment: use setEnable(true/false) to make your edittext editable and noneditable..

Comment: There is another question related to the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731017/how-to-make-an-edittext-uneditable-disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this to make eddittext not editable:

```
noteDetailsview.setEnabled(false);
```

and this to make it editable again:

```
noteDetailsview.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use noteDetailview.setEnable(true/false) to enable/disable the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these methods:

```
 public void getFocous(EditText edit) {
        edit.setFocusable(true);
        edit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        edit.requestFocus();
        edit.requestFocusFromTouch();
    }



    public void loseFocous(EditText edit) {
        edit.clearFocus();
        edit.setFocusable(false);
    }
```