# Disable EditText with radio button checked

Tags: android, android-edittext, radio-button

This code not working , what's Wrong? I don't want to allow user input until `radiobutton2` is checked

```
EditText t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

 RadioButton  rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
 RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
 RadioGroup  rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);


    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton1)
            {
                t4.setEnabled(false);
            }

            if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton2)
            {
                t4.setEnabled(true);
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Disabling edittext in Android is a bit cumbersome. Try adding `t4.setFocusable(false);` with combination of `t4.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23197277/7320259 hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

```
t4.setEnable(rb2.isChecked());

rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                t4.setEnable(isChecked);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the code given below?

```
EditText t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

RadioButton  rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
RadioGroup  rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);


rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton1)
        {
            changeEditTextAvailability(t4, false);
        }

        if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton2)
        {
            changeEditTextAvailability(t4, true);
        }


    }
});

private void changeEditTextAvailability(EditText editText, boolean status) {
    editText.setFocusable(status);
    editText.setEnabled(status);
    editText.setCursorVisible(status);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(status)
}
```

Cheers,

Renc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**Check if “Radiobutton” is checked:** `isChecked()`

**Disable EditText in android:** `setFocusable()`

```
EditText t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

RadioButton  rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
RadioGroup  rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);

if (rb.isChecked()) {
   t4.setFocusable(true);
} else {
   t4.setFocusable(false);
}

if (rb2.isChecked()) {
   t4.setFocusable(false);
} else {
   t4.setFocusable(true);
}
```

Comment: this works only first time checked. mean if once i tried both then t4 disabled forever. again i need to go back.  can you tell me how to code so that it work many times as i change selection of radiobutton??

Comment: @MuhammadAkram the problem is why you need to check two buttons at the same time??

Comment: @MuhammadAkram ok i change you can try

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (cbProhibitEditPW.isChecked()) { // disable editing password
       editTextPassword.setFocusable(false);
       editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // user touches widget on phone with touch screen
       editTextPassword.setClickable(false); // user navigates with wheel and selects widget
} else { // enable editing of password
       editTextPassword.setFocusable(true);
       editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
       editTextPassword.setClickable(true);
}
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not initialized the validations after initializing the views
Try this in on `onCreate()`

```
EditText t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

RadioButton  rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
RadioGroup  rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);

if (rb.isChecked()) {
   t4.setFocusable(true);
}

if (rb2.isChecked()) {
   t4.setFocusable(false);
}
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton1)
            {
                t4.setEnabled(false);
            }

            if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton2)
            {
                t4.setEnabled(true);
            }


        }
    });
```

This will restrict user to input when screen launches

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to call `setFocusable(false)` in addition to `setEnabled(false)` on the EditText.  Change your code as shown below:

```
    EditText t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

 RadioButton  rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
 RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
 RadioGroup  rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.G1);


    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton1)
            {
                t4.setEnabled(false);
                t4.setFocusable(false);
            }

            if(checkedId==R.id.radioButton2)
            {
                t4.setEnabled(true);
                t4.setFocusable(true);

            }


        }
    });
```