# Making not editable EditText component

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text. How can I make it non editable from the code.
 By giving  the tag `android:editable`  we can do in the layout.. But I need to do it in the code...Pls Help

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is as simple as

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: its not working.. Please help.. The focus is still in the edit text. when i click that the i can edit

Comment: I got it....use edt.setClickable(false); edt.setFocusable(false); Also dont add properties like android:numeric in edit text..Otherwise it won't work  <EditText android:id="@+id/edt" 
   android:layout_width="200px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"  android:maxLength="15">
  </EditText>

Comment: @jennifer --- android:enabled="false" use this in XML.

Answer (score 2):

Refer [EDITTEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910135/can-we-have-uneditable-text-in-edittext)

```
        edt.setClickable(false);
    edt.setFocusable(false);


      ***Layout***

<EditText android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="200px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" android:textSize="18sp"  android:maxLength="15">
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didnt find yet an answer, i have found this in the net:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2854

Answer (score 1):

I am using for this problem, this solution:

```
valueText.setEnabled(false);
valueText.setClickable(false);
valueText.setFocusable(false);

//Just for better text vision
valueText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```