# Want to protect Edit Text from be changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my code...

```
            package com.bmc;


            public class Details extends Activity 
            {

                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.details);

                    EditText desc,sol;

            /*
                Some code here...........


             */     desc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_desc1);
                    sol=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_sol);
                   desc.setEnabled(false);
                   sol.setEnabled(false);
                   sol.setClickable(false);
                   desc.setClickable(false);

                }

            }
```

Here sol becomes write protected but desc does not. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: The "Some code here" bit is pretty major to miss out. We have no idea what you're doing to initialise these, where you're putting them, what layout types they are in, anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
desc.setEnabled(false);
desc.setClickable(false);
desc.setFocusable(false);
sol.setEnabled(false);
sol.setClickable(false);
sol.setFocusable(false);
```

Let me know how it goes.

Also, more help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824676/making-not-editable-edittext-component) if needed.

Comment: ya it works..!! but how to reset it to be editable? making them true didnt works...

Comment: Making them true should work. Maybe you are doing something else wrong or something.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

`android:editable="false"`

in the edittext.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, the best way to do it from code. It will also restrict your keyboard to pop up for typing.

Actually it disabled you key stroke on that `edittext`.

```
EditText desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_desc1);
desc.setKeyListener(null);
EditText sol = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_sol);
sol.setKeyListener(null);
```