# Make EditText field uneditable

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to make EditText Field uneditable over property inputType when

```
inputType="textPassword"
```

My problem is that following code line makes the password visible.

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Already tried following, but remains editable

```
password.setEnabled(false)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928711/how-to-make-edittext-not-editable

Comment: but it should be editable again after some logic

Comment: I think you can also call `setFocusable(false)`. Since it's not focusable you won't be able to enter anything.

Comment: already tried, but setFocusable(true) won't work after

Comment: if you play with setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode it should be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you play with :

```
edittext.setFocusable();
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode();
```

You should be able to make the EditText editable/uneditable when you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using this: [How to make EditText not editable through XML in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928711/how-to-make-edittext-not-editable/6174440#6174440)

You said that you wanted your field to be editable after some logic. Do this:

```
KeyListener keyLis = textView.getKeyListener();
textView.setKeyListener(null);
```

Then, when you want your `TextView` to be editable again, do this:

```
textView.setKeyListener(keyLis);
```

Documentation for `TextView` class:

Two methods:

[`getKeyListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getKeyListener%28%29)

[`setKeyListener(KeyListener keyLis)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getKeyListener())

**EDIT**

I didn't find any beautiful answers, but I did find a few alternative ways to do this:

1. To make uneditable

   `valueText.setEnabled(false);
   valueText.setClickable(false);
       valueText.setFocusable(false);`

And then,

```
valueText.setEnabled(true);
valueText.setClickable(true);
valueText.setFocusable(true);
```

2. You can also change what happens when the text is edited to make nothing happen: [Can we have uneditable text in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910135/can-we-have-uneditable-text-in-edittext)

   3. There are some other very wild solutions, out there. They're not beautiful at all, though.

I recommend using the initial solution, unless somebody finds a quicker way.

Sorry I couldn't find a better way to do this :(

Comment: looks like a workaround, is there any more beautiful solution?

Comment: I don't know. I will do some research.