# how to disable EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am writing an app which requires at a time the EditText view to be uneditable. I used editText.setEnabled(false); it is greyed out alright, but the IME still pops up, and I still could type in characters, why could this be???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code

Answer (score 4):

```
            if (cbProhibitEditPW.isChecked()) { // disable editing password
                editTextPassword.setFocusable(false);
                editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // user touches widget on phone with touch screen
                editTextPassword.setClickable(false); // user navigates with wheel and selects widget
                isProhibitEditPassword= true;
            }
            else { // enable editing of password
                editTextPassword.setFocusable(true);
                editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editTextPassword.setClickable(true);
                isProhibitEditPassword= false;
            }
```