# How to make textinputedittext editable and uneditable programmatically

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext

I am currently using TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout. And wants to control editabilility programmatically. Make it editable on button click and uneditable clicking another button.

```
  deliveryQuantityTie.setFocusable(false);
```

set focus false make uneditable but set focus true does not make it editable.
i also tried with toggling clickable,cursor visible , setkeylistener , nothing make it editable again.

what should i use to make it editable and uneditable in java code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make EditText ReadOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384004/make-edittext-readonly)

Answer (score 2):

make your editText property `setFocusable(true`) and `setEnabled(true)` to true to make it editable it will solve your problem

Comment: problem solved but setFocusable(false) working fine but setFocusable(true) is not working from java code.

Comment: before setFocusable(true) you can enable your editext and check if it's working

Answer (score 1):

## Use setEnable(boolean)

> How to disable?

```
TextInputEditText tie = findViewById(R.id.my_textInputEditText);
tie.setEnabled(false);
```

#### Result: Disabled

[image]

> How to enable again?

```
tie.setEnabled(true);
```

#### Result: Enabled

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this

```
fragmentRegistrationFirstScreenBinding.etName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                make editable and let user edit them
            }else {
                do not make editable
            }
        }
    });
```