# How to set editable true/false EditText in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext

We can set editable property of `EditText` in XML layout but not programatically, but there is no `setEditable()` method!

If `EditText` is not **Enabled** [ by `setEnabled(false)`] it still **Editable**!

Comment: EditText.setEnabled(false); if you set this, the edittext disable.100%

Comment: How it possible, I checked, It disable your edittext.

Comment: Yes it may be disable but we cant copy value of that edittext using this.

Comment: The most reliable way to achieve that result is using `UI.setReadOnly(myEditText, true)` from [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib). There are a few properties that have to be set, which you can check out [in the source code](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/62299c79d100e38627600907e755d563de072234/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/UI.java#L264).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replicate android:editable="false" in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did it in a easier way , setEditable and setFocusable false. but you should check this.

[How to replicate android:editable="false" in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code)

Answer (score 52):

This may help:

```
if (cbProhibitEditPW.isChecked()) { // disable editing password
       editTextPassword.setFocusable(false);
       editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // user touches widget on phone with touch screen
       editTextPassword.setClickable(false); // user navigates with wheel and selects widget
       isProhibitEditPassword= true;
} else { // enable editing of password
       editTextPassword.setFocusable(true);
       editTextPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
       editTextPassword.setClickable(true);
       isProhibitEditPassword= false;
}
```

Comment: The edit text will still receive key events after disable above, combine the answer with Sumit Sonome answer below to fully make it non-editable.

Answer (score 9):

Fetch the **KeyListener** value of `EditText` by `editText.getKeyListener()` 
and store in the **KeyListener** type variable, which will contain
the Editable property value:

```
KeyListener variable;
variable = editText.getKeyListener();
```

Set the Editable property of `EditText` to false as:

```
 edittext.setKeyListener(null);
```

Now set Editable property of `EditText` to true as:

```
editText.setKeyListener(variable);
```

**Note:** In XML the default Editable property of `EditText` should be true.

Answer (score 7):

How to do it programatically :

To enable EditText use:

```
et.setEnabled(true);
```

To disable EditText use:

```
et.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

hope this one helps you out:

```
edittext1.setKeyListener(null);
edittext1.setCursorVisible(false);
edittext1.setPressed(false);
edittext1.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution, plus `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` as some other solutions also disable scrolling as well as editing

Answer (score 5):

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details as to why this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Once focus of edit text is removed, it would not allow you to type even if you set it to focusable again.

Here is a way around it

```
if (someCondition)
   editTextField.setFocusable(false);
else
   editTextField.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Setting it true in `setFocusableInTouchMode()` seems to do the trick.

Comment: setFocusableInTouchMode save my day! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

It works fine...

Answer (score 2):

Try this it is working fine for me..

```
EditText.setInputType(0);
EditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter()
{
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) 
{
return source.length() < 1 ? dest.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";

}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `setEditable(false)` is deprecated, use `textView.setKeyListener(null);` to make editText non-clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `setEditable(false)` is deprecated and we can't use it programmatically, we can use another way to solve it with `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)`

It means we change the input type of edit text. We set it to NULL so it becomes not editable.

Here's the sample that might be useful (I code this on my onCreateView method Fragment):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfragment, container, false);
    EditText sample = view.findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
    sample.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Hope this will answer the problem

Answer (score 0):

An easy and safe method:

```
editText.clearFocus();
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make an uneditable editText field:

```kotlin
findViewById<EditText>(R.id.yourEditTextId).isEnabled = false
```