# How to set Editable EditText with Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my application I have an `EditText` and a `Switch` (view), but I want if the Switch is off for `EditText` to be not editable. Also, when the Switch is on, the `EditText` should be editable.

**My Switch listener :**

```
infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            isRemember = true;
        } else {
            isRemember = false;
        }
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555455/how-to-set-editable-true-false-edittext-in-android-programmatically) might help!

Comment: Have you tried using edittext.setFocusable(false); or editText.setEnabled(false); when the switch is off i.e in the else part of your code and the vice versa ?

Answer (score 0):

```
infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            isRemember = true;
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        return src.length() < 1 ? dst.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            isRemember = false;
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            isRemember = true;
        } else {
            isRemember = false;
        }
        if (isRemember) {
            infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitchText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        } else {
            infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitchText.setFocusable(false);
        }
    }
});

} else {
    hideView(infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitch);
}
if (isRemember) {
    infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitchText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
} else {
    infoSerialFrag_rememberSwitchText.setFocusable(false);
}
```

Comment: I tried edit your answer and reformat your code. Why do the if else's not match up?