# How to make EditText that cannot be editted?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to make the editText that shows the text but not as editable type. I cant use textview there because i am using same component for entering the values. How to achieve it?
Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`editText.setFocusable(false);` `editText.setClickable(false);` 
the two property which turn EditText to non focusable and unclickable which leads to a non editable Edittext

Comment: Thank you lot... This is what i was expecting...

Comment: How to do this for buttons? This code ot working for buttons...?

Comment: ya, you can do for that button also

Comment: If that button contains popup method such as showDialog(0) ? i.e date and time picker, this code which you gave wont work ah?

Comment: obiviously, as it disable your button click

Comment: ya.. I have commented the functionality and your coding works... For editText, Long clicking the edittext is making to paste the clipboard contents. Can i give editText.setLongClickable(false); ?

Comment: It has worked Perfectly... Thanks for the timing Help...

Answer (score 5):

Make EditText Read only.

Like this:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Or from code:
`edittext.setEnabled(false)` or `edittext.setFocusable(false)` or `edittext.setFocusableinTouchMode(false)`

Answer (score 3):

try this....

```
EditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter()
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) 
    {
        return source.length() < 1 ? dest.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";

    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
android:editable="false"
```

Comment: This solution has since been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, open the layout file and add `android:editable="false"` attribute.

```
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/editText1" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:editable="false"
>
```

Answer (score -5):

hi if you use edit text so u give this property in edit text

`android:hint="write any thing"`  , but dont use `Android:text=""`

Comment: For that you can use TextView

Comment: How does it deal to the question?