# edit text field not getting edited

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an activity which has an `EditText` and a `Button`. The data in the `EditText` is not editable in the beginning, but it becomes editable when the `Button` is pressed.I have tried using `android:editable="false"` in the xml layout , but it is not working. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first set the TextEdit editable property to false in your xml layout :

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

And then when the button is clicked, set the TextEdit to editable :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            input.setClickable(true);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: hey there is no setEditable() functions for the edit text fields.Hoew can I do it otherwise?

Comment: Oops. Unfortunately, `editable` property is only exposed through XML Programmatically, you should use either `setEnabled` or `setFocusable` or `setClickable`. However, when using these methods, you won't be able to select and copy the text... code updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setEnabled(true); or editText.setEnabled(false);
```

if cant works then [Editable false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:id="@+id/urId"
    android:clickable="True" />
```

This worked for me, try your luck.

Comment: <EditText
    ...
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:clickable="True" />

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your answer. If you want to show code here, you should indent it by 4 spaces. This automatically puts a line in `code markdown`.