# how to avoid editText change using textWatcher?

Tags: java, android, text, android-edittext

I have an editText that i want to control in length.

how can i avoid the user from entering a character which will lead the text to be longer than X ?

I have thought to use `beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {`

but then i'm not sure how to skip adding the character if i want.

The length is determined dynamically - getting this from the server side on activity start

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/911407/1665507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need to stop the user from entering a text longer than `x`, simply put `android:maxLength="x"` as an attribute for your EditText.

Or,

`mEditText.setFilters( new InputFilter[] 
     { 
      new InputFilter.LengthFilter(<length>)
     } );`

Comment: The length is determined dynamically - getting this from the server side on activity start

Comment: Set it using Java then ?

Comment: `The method setMaxLength(int) is undefined for the type EditText`

Comment: Sorry! Extremely sorry! It skipped my mind in my haste to answer. please check my updated answer now.

Answer (score 0):

use following property in edittext

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Comment: The length is determined dynamically - getting this from the server side on activity start

Comment: so you can code into .java file, make string object and get the length of string into your edittext using this property in dynamically way.

Comment: The method setMaxLength(int) is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: its depends on version.