# Replace the content of Linear layout at onclick button android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to replace the content of the linear layout which has button and textview with an editText type="phone" after an onclick event of button. They're all in the located in the same page.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: LinearLayout has methods to clear all elements from it, after which you should be able to add new views programmatically.

Comment: what i understand from your question, just play with "editable" property of EditText and you get what you want.
follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code
Note: no need of another textview, one edit text work here perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to remove all Views.

```
lauout.removeAllViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make two separate fragments and use a fragmenttransaction to replace one with the other.

See fragmenttransactions:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question

1) There are 3 views Button, TextView and EditText under one LinearLayout

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My TextView " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" // with input type phone
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And You want to remove the textview and replace it with Edit Text on Button Click
like this

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry If i misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

place all of your three elements in the layout in your xml_layout, and set the `EditText` visibility to `"gone"`, then when clicking the `Button` you mentioned, just set the `Button` and the `TextView` visibility to `"gone"` and the `EditText` visibility to `"visible"`:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
    .
    .
    .>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        .
        .
        .
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        .
        .
        .
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        .
        .
        .
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

when clicking the Button:

```
public OnClickListener onButClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        text.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     

    }
};
```